# Is it wrong to say "I hope this does not inconvenience you in any way"?

Tags: grammaticality, politeness

I recently had a dilemma regarding this. While the above sentence sounds okay to my ears, "I hope this does not cause any inconvenience to you" sounds more grammatically correct. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are perfect English. Style difference only. If you're speaking it, I'd use **doesn't**. My choice would be the first one because it's shorter and doesn't turn a perfectly good verb, **inconvenience**, into a noun that requires a vaguer more generic verb, *cause*.

Answer (score 4):

Your sentence is perfectly fine and a recognized use. "[Inconvenience](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inconvenience)" is a verb as well as a noun.